# why won't django load my view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I get an 'Page not found' error when i try to load the site.(127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/)

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^catalog/$', 'preview.views.home'),
# Example:
# (r'^ecomstore/', include('ecomstore.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
# (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),    
)
```

And in the package preview my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html")
```

"index.html" is in the folder ecomstore/templates, the variable TEMPLATE_DIRS is set to this directory.

Strangely i got no debug trace, but the DEBUG variable is set to true
Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: If you have `debug` enabled in your settings, it should give you a traceback on your error page - posting that would be helpful.

Comment: How did you start the Django dev server? What was the output it gave during startup?

Comment: Can you post what your `hosts` file is showing? On linux/mac it is `/etc/hosts` and on Windows its is `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 0):

What does your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` look like in your `settings.py` and what path is your `index.html` in on disk that you are expecting it to load and render?  It sounds like it's trying to find `index.html` but cannot find it, but without the debug traceback it's tough to tell.

Comment: I would think if it couldn't find the template it'd be giving a 500, with a TemplateDoesNotExist error or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, maybe you can try http://localhost:8000/catalog/

I ran into the same situation this morning on my Windows XP machine. When I switched from using 127.0.0.1 to localhost, it just started working. I still haven't figured out what I did to make it stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your root (project-level) URLconf, or is it from one of your apps? If it's from one of your apps, is it being properly included from the root URLconf?

I ask because the code you show should work, if Django is indeed reading it.

Another idea: is anything in that view raising an Http404 exception? Either directly, or via `get_object_or_404`?

I also second the requests above to share the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I capitalized the I in index.html.  So it was looking for index.html and I had Index.html.  Took me an hour to find that.  Just double check.